# iOS Location Updates only received 50% of the time when device is locked PIN or No PIN

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I am seeing some unexpected behavior in my iOS app when testing with the screen locked.

The process flow is:

1) App receives a silent push notification via content-available flag

2) App requests location information via existing CLLocationManager startUpdatingLocation call

3) Upon receipt of a location update, API call is made with information

The flow works as expected when the app is in the foreground as well as when the app is in the background.

If I lock the device with the screen lock button (with or without a PIN enabled) upon receipt of the push notification, the startLocationUpdates method is called, but the callback didUpdateLocations is received only about 50% of the time.

Any information on the cause of this behavior is appreciated.

Basic Code Flow

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    if(self.deviceLocationManager == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"setUpLocation - Creating a LocationManager.");     
        self.deviceLocationManager                 = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.deviceLocationManager.delegate        = self;
        self.deviceLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
        self.deviceLocationManager.distanceFilter  = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
        self.deviceLocationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;

        if ([self.deviceLocationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])
        {
            [self.deviceLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        }
        if ([self.deviceLocationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:)])
        {
            [self.deviceLocationManager setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:YES];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        self.deviceLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
        self.deviceLocationManager.distanceFilter  = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
        self.deviceLocationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
    }
    [self.deviceLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}


-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    NSLog(@":::: NEW LOCATION UPDATE RECEIVED ::::");
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
    CLLocationAccuracy horizontalAccuracy = location.horizontalAccuracy;
    NSLog(@"::::appDelegate - NEW LOCATION UPDATE ACCURACY IS - %f",horizontalAccuracy);
   //Make the API call here.......
}
```

Comment: is your prob solved??

Comment: Not Yet, I'm going to test with the 10.3 beta 5 and see if I get any different results.

Comment: Same behavior with iOS 10.3. Beta 5.  Initial testing revealed 25% success rate.